# CMake function ```find_package()``` does not find config.cmake configuration files

Tags: c++, cmake, sdk, cmakelists-options

I installed the fCWT external library following the instructions from the official repository: https://github.com/fastlib/fCWT

And in the Ubuntu default path /usr/local/share/fcwt/cmake the configuration files **fCWT-config.cmake** and **fCWT-config-release.cmake** are present. However, when using the `find_package(fCWT REQUIRED)` function in a QT Creator build together with CMakeLists.txt, CMake gives an error:

> CMakeLists.txt:14: error: By not providing "FindfCWT.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "fCWT", but CMake did not find one. Could not find a package configuration file provided by "fCWT" with any of the following names:

> fCWTConfig.cmake
> fcwt-config.cmake

> Add the installation prefix of "fCWT" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "fCWT_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "fCWT" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

This seems strange to me because it finds the other library (GSL) I use in my small project. My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

project(fft LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(GSL REQUIRED)
find_package(fCWT REQUIRED)

include_directories(${GSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${fCWT_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(/lib/include)
include_directories(/usr/local/include)

add_executable(fft main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(fft PRIVATE ${GSL_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(fft PRIVATE ${fCWT_LIBRARY})
```

I've tried specifying the path to the configuration files using CMake commands:

```
set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH fCWT-config.cmake REQUIRED)
set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /usr/local/share/fcwt/cmake/fCWT-config.cmake REQUIRED)
set (fCWT-config.cmake_DIR = /usr/local/share/fcwt/cmake/ REQUIRED)
list(APPEND CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH /usr/local/share/fcwt/cmake)
```

listing them before `find_package(fCWT REQUIRED)`

Thank you for paying attention to my question. I will be glad to receive any advice on how to fix this error.

Comment: CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH should contain a prefix like `/usr/local/share/fcwt`, not a full pathname.

Comment: You should also adopt modern CMake. `FindGSL.cmake` exports a `GSL::gsl` target that knows what include paths and linker flags to pass. And it looks like `fCWT` also defines a target you can import.

Comment: The error message clearly tells: `set "fCWT_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.`. Why do you attempt to set `fCWT-config.cmake_DIR` variable instead of `fCWT_DIR`? Also, in the `set` command REQUIRED keyword has no special meaning, the same is about equal sign (`=`).

Comment: "And in the Ubuntu default path /usr/local/share/fcwt/cmake the configuration files fCWT-config.cmake and fCWT-config-release.cmake are present" - But the error message clearly tells that CMake searches files `fCWTConfig.cmake` or `fcwt-config.cmake`. The file `fCWT-config.cmake` which you have, doesn't fulfill CMake expectations (name of that file differs from the expected one `fcwt-config.cmake`).

Comment: You should remove `=` and `REQUIRED` from your cmake `set` commands, I wouldn't be surprised if cmake is interpreting these as part of your values

Comment: @Tsyvarev was right, I renamed the fCWT-config.cmake file to fCWTConfig.cmake and it found it. However, I’m not sure how correct it was to simply rename the configuration file by going into the folder with administrator rights

Comment: "I’m not sure how correct it was to simply rename the configuration file by going into the folder with administrator rights" - Normally, one should not do such things. But in your case the project itself (fCWT) is incorrect: it assigns incorrect name to the config file. You may note about that inconsistency in your [bugreport](https://github.com/fastlib/fCWT/issues/57),